# How to add a link inside a tool-tip Prime faces

Tags: primefaces, hyperlink, tooltip

I tried using the example given in the Prime Faces guide but I can't find the way to actually add the link inside the tooltip, besides how can I hideDelay it?

Lets start with this:

```
 <h:outputLink id="lnk" value="#">
 <h:outputText value="PrimeFaces Home" />
 </h:outputLink>
   <p:tooltip for="lnk">
 <h:outputText value="Visit PrimeFaces Home" />
  </p:tooltip>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uhhmmmm there only is a link **outside** the tooltip in your code. There is no link inside it.

```
<h:outputLink id="lnk" value="#">
   <h:outputText value="PrimeFaces Home" />
</h:outputLink>
<p:tooltip for="lnk">
    <h:outputLink id="lnk" value="http://www.primefaces.org">
        <h:outputText value="Visit PrimeFaces Home" />
    <h:outputLink>
</p:tooltip>
```

Works

Comment: Thanks man, it works. Anyway, i tried adding a hideDelay on the tool tip but it seems to ignore the delay.






                                                    


<h:outputLink id="lnk" value="#">
   <h:outputText value="PrimeFaces Home" />
   </h:outputLink>
   <p:tooltip for="lnk" hideDelay="500">
       <h:outputLink id="lnk" value="http://www.primefaces.org" >
           <h:outputText value="Visit PrimeFaces Home" />
       </h:outputLink>
  </p:tooltip>